# date_trunc function does not work with the spark dataframe while adding new column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to use the `date_trunc` function on the dataframe which has the date column so that I can create new column that would give me information about which quarter the record is associated with.

Stuffs that i have tried is as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val test = Seq(("2010-03-05"),("2018-01-16"),("2018-04-20")).toDF("TestDates")
display(test)  //this displays the date in the notebook

val datetrunctest = test.withColumn("Quarter", date_trunc("QUARTER",$"TestDates"))
display(datetrunctest)  //this gives me an error saying **error: not found: value date_trunc**
```

Also when I try to use the import statement with the function name it gives me error as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_trunc
Error : value date_trunc is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```

I am able to use the same function in spark sql as below by saving above dataframe test as a table "DailyDates":

```
val ddd = spark.sql("Select TestDates,date_trunc('QUARTER', TestDates) as QuarterDate from test.DailyDates")
display(ddd)
```

I have lot of transformation/aggregation that needs to be performed on the dataframe so I am looking to find an way by which I could make this work on the dataframe by adding additional column. According to the documentation if you are using spark version greater than 2.3.0 this should work and I am using spark version 2.4.3 .

Snapshot image for the spark version :
[image]

Document Link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_trunc-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Does anyone have any idea on what could be the issue and how I can get this working?

Comment: Looks totally fine, just make sure you use spark version >2.3.0

Comment: @koiralo I have verified that the version that I am using is 2.4.3 but it is still giving me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of spark you are using,

Open Spark shell Terminal and enter the command

`sc.version  Or  spark-submit --version`

Make sure you import the function

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

and then

The function requires the parameter to be Column

```
public static Column quarter(Column e)
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val test = Seq(("2010-03-05"),("2018-01-16"),("2018-04-20")).toDF("TestDates")
val datetrunctest = test.withColumn("Quarter", quarter($"TestDates"))
```

Comment: What is the difference between the answer and the question asked?

Comment: I have already edited the answer before your comment.

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola I have actually done the steps that you are specifying and also mentioned that as a part of the question but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you confirm the version is output >=2.3.0?

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola I updated the question with the spark version snapshot image.

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola Are you able to run the code snippet and getting the expected output?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya are you using pyspark?

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola I am using spark with scala and not pyspark

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya Try this once ```import org.apache.spark.SPARK_VERSION``` and then ```SPARK_VERSION``` If the version is proper the probably issue with the installation of conflicting spark packages

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola I am using Databricks cluster and it is showing spark version 2.4.3 and also trying your suggestion gives the same output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221562/discussion-between-shrey-jakhmola-and-nikunj-kakadiya).

Answer (score 0):

The same code for the date_trunc started working without any code change. I don't know if there was something wrong with the cluster in the backend but it did not work for half a day and started working in the evening. Weird. If this happens again I will raise a support ticket with the Databricks with the details.

I was also able to figure out a work around solution without using the date_trunc function which is as below if that helps someone for their use case.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val test = Seq(("2010-03-05"),("2018-01-16"),("2018-04-20"),("2018-08-15"),("2018-11-30")).toDF("TestDates")

val datetrunctest = test.withColumn("Year",year($"TestDates"))
.withColumn("Quarter", quarter($"TestDates"))
.withColumn("QuarterDate", when($"Quarter" === 1, concat($"Year",(lit("-01-01"))))                                                                                                                   
.when($"Quarter" === 2, concat($"Year",(lit("-04-01"))))                                                                                                                
.when($"Quarter" === 3, concat($"Year",(lit("-07-01"))))                                                                                                                    
.when($"Quarter" === 4, concat($"Year",(lit("-10-01")))))
.drop("Year","Quarter")

display(datetrunctest)
```